Unable to pass icon, channel_id, data after migrating to v1 FCM from legacy
As per Firebase, I have migrated my FCM to new FCM V1.
But Everything is not perfectly worked as expected
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(fcmModal.getmActivity());
    JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();

    try {
      JSONObject messageObject = new JSONObject();
      messageObject.put("token", fcmModal.getUserFcmToken());

      JSONObject notificationObject = new JSONObject();
      notificationObject.put("title", fcmModal.getTitle());
      notificationObject.put("body", fcmModal.getBody());
//      notificationObject.put("icon", fcmModal.getIcon());
//      notificationObject.put("channel_name", fcmModal.getChannelId());
//      notificationObject.put("requestCode", fcmModal.getRequestCode());




      messageObject.put("notification", notificationObject);

//      JSONObject dataObj = new JSONObject();
//      dataObj.put("requestCode",fcmModal.getRequestCode());
//      messageObject.put("data",dataObj);

      mainObj.put("message", messageObject);

      JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, postUrl, mainObj, response -> {
//        showLog("request: Success");
      }, volleyError -> {
        showLog("Error: " + volleyError);
      }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
          String accessKey = getAccessToken();
          Map<String, String> header = new HashMap<>();
          header.put("content-type", "application/json");
          header.put("authorization", "Bearer " + accessKey);
          return header;
        }
      };

      requestQueue.add(request);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
      showLog("Volley: " + e.getMessage());
    }

  }


it just works when passing title and body only. But
it gives volley server error when passing other parameters, (Commented out in above code), such as icon, channel_id, requestCodes, data

I tried changing as per the attachment But I still got same error.

Please help me to figure out the issues.
It is very important for my project with icons and request codes too.

Why did I get down vote? Am i doing wrong? Please help me figuring out.
